# GroupBox with radioButtons enabling another groupBox doesn't keep button state

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have three groupBoxes with two radioButtons each. Buttons in the first box
enable/disable the second groupBox. Buttons in the second enable/disable the
third groupBox.

This is how it's supposed to work.

The second and third groupBoxes are disabled by default.
radioButton in the first box sends signal toggled(bool) to enable the second
box. There, radioButton that deactivates the third box is clicked by default, a second radioButton sends signal toggled(bool) to the third box enabling it.

What actually happens is that when I enable the second box, the third box
becomes enabled. When I toggle buttons in the second box I can enable/disable the third box, but when I again disable the second box from the first and then enable it again, the third box is enabled regardles of which button is clicked in the second box.

What gives?

Fair game, here's an example (tried to make it as short as I could with Designer)(imports, first class and 'if **name** == ...' at the end of the file contain additional 4 spaces so that code shows as code, delete them to run):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
    self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
    self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
    self.radioButton_2.setChecked(True)
    self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
    self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
    self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButton)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.groupBox_2.setEnabled(False)
    self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
    self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox_2)
    self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
    self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
    self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
    self.radioButton_3.setChecked(True)
    self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_3)
    self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
    self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
    self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.radioButton_4)
    self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.groupBox_3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.groupBox_3.setEnabled(False)
    self.groupBox_3.setObjectName("groupBox_3")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 30))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    self.radioButton.toggled['bool'].connect(self.groupBox_2.setEnabled)
    self.radioButton_4.toggled['bool'].connect(self.groupBox_3.setEnabled)
    self.radioButton_2.toggled['bool'].connect(self.groupBox_3.setDisabled)
    self.radioButton_3.toggled['bool'].connect(self.groupBox_3.setDisabled)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "whatever"))
    self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Off"))
    self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sensors"))
    self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Control method"))
    self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "On/Off"))
    self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PID"))
    self.groupBox_3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PID settings"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Maybe an example would help here. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First off (and I mean this in the nicest way) that is some really ugly code.  I have taken your code and cleaned it up and using Python 3.7 with pyqt5 on Win10 it works fine and should be a lot easier to understand.  I hope this helps you down a more structured path to development.  Keep in mind that you often have to go back and revisit and/or reuse old code that you have written best to write it in a way that makes it really easy to understand at a glance.

```
from sys import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class BoxOne(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QGroupBox.__init__(self, CentrPane)
      # Reference back to parent
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setTitle('Main Controller')

        self.radBtnOff = QRadioButton('Off')
        self.radBtnOff.setChecked(True)
        self.radBtnOff.toggled['bool'].connect(self.BoxTwoOff)
        self.radBtnSnsr = QRadioButton('Sensors')
        self.radBtnSnsr.toggled['bool'].connect(self.BoxTwoOn)

        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radBtnOff)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radBtnSnsr)

        self.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

    def BoxTwoOff(self):
      # I assume you did not mean to leave Box Three Enabled
        self.CntrPane.SecndBox.radBtnOnOff.setChecked(True)
        self.CntrPane.SecndBox.setDisabled(True)

    def BoxTwoOn(self):
        self.CntrPane.SecndBox.setEnabled(True)

class BoxTwo(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QGroupBox.__init__(self, CentrPane)
      # Reference back to parent
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setTitle('Control Method')
        self.setEnabled(False)

        self.radBtnOnOff = QRadioButton('On/Off')
        self.radBtnOnOff.setChecked(True)
        self.radBtnOnOff.toggled['bool'].connect(self.BoxThreeOff)
        self.radBtnPID = QRadioButton('PID')
        self.radBtnPID.toggled['bool'].connect(self.BoxThreeOn)

        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radBtnOnOff)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.radBtnPID)

        self.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

    def BoxThreeOff(self):
        self.CntrPane.ThirdBox.setDisabled(True)

    def BoxThreeOn(self):
        self.CntrPane.ThirdBox.setEnabled(True)

class BoxThree(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QGroupBox.__init__(self, CentrPane)
      # Reference back to parent
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane

        self.setTitle('PID Settings')
        self.setEnabled(False)

        self.MyEditor = QTextEdit('Editorial')

        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.MyEditor)

        self.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
      # Reference back to parent
        self.MainWin = MainWin

        self.FirstBox = BoxOne(self)
        self.SecndBox = BoxTwo(self)
        self.ThirdBox = BoxThree(self)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.FirstBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SecndBox, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ThirdBox, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

class MenuToolBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
      # Reference back to parent
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.menuBar()

class StatusBar(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
      # Reference back to parent
        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.MainMenu = MainWin.statusBar()

class UI_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, AppDesktop):
        super(UI_MainWindow, self).__init__(AppDesktop)
      # Reference back to parent
        self.MainDeskTop = AppDesktop

        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
      # Left, Top, Width, Height
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.MenuToolBar = MenuToolBar(self)

        self.StatusBar = StatusBar(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp = QApplication([])

    MainGui = UI_MainWindow(MainApp.desktop())
    MainGui.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

Comment: Now, that is some real nice looking code. Thank you for taking time to disentangle the spaghetti. The code I have presented was spitted out by qt designer, no, I haven't written it by hand... I thought it's alright to use as is. Apart from the fact that code produced via designer was ugly, could you please try to point out where did I do wrong?

Comment: I mean: is there a way to achieve that from within qt5 designer?

Comment: Also: idealy, when I enable the second box, then enable the third box, then disable the second box, when I enable the second box again the third box keeps being enabled - like it was last time when we enabled the second box. So that boxes 'remember' their last state. Is that doable?

Comment: Yes the designer does create some mighty ugly code ;) where you went wrong was using the designer.  I say that for 2 reason (1st) as you know it creates some mighty ugly code (2nd) you do not learn how things interact and means implementation of what you trying to do will be a lot harder

Comment: As for doing it with the Designer I am sure you can -- cannot say how because frankly I see no point in using it because maintenance afterwards is a nightmare and I am always concerned about that.

Comment: Yes you can do what you are asking but it kind of depends on how you want to implement that.  You just need to decide under what conditions you want things activated and not activated then adjust your activation functions accordingly.  If you want to save states between executions then use QSettings if you just need to save the last states prior to deactivation then create a variable and use that.

Comment: Addendum: As an effort to help you understand things I would suggest that you take a stab at trying to determine where your original code went wrong.  The problem with ugly code like that is it is a nightmare to debug and it was quicker for me to rewrite what you were doing than try to figure out where the bug(s) were.  Also if this solves the issue please indicate it so that others know that the problem was resolved.